# jQuery autocomplete not working with Turbolinks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 4. This snippet from my `shared.js.coffee` works fine *without* turbolinks:

```
jQuery ->
  $('input.autocomplete,textarea.autocomplete').each (index, item) =>
    sel = $(item)
    sel.autocomplete
      source: sel.data('autocomplete-source')
      minLength: 1
```

But when I use [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), it only works on a page refresh. It does not work after navigating through the site.

I've read [Rails 4, Turbolinks, and Delegated Event Handling in jQuery](http://www.iexposure.com/2012/10/26/rails-4-turbolinks-and-delegated-event-handling-in-jquery), so I have some idea of what is going wrong, but I'm not yet sure how to fix the problem.

And, a related question: can anyone comment definitely if the [jQuery UI autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L22) -- or for that matter, plugins in general -- is/are designed to work with Turbolinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

> "if you have a large codebase with lots of `$(el).bind(...)` Turbolinks will surprise you. Most part of your JavaScripts will stop working in usual way. It's because the nodes on which you bind events no longer exist."

Usage:

```
# Gemfile:
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# JavaScript manifest file:
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

Perhaps, at some point, the jQuery `$.widget` function will offer an option to bind differently, but until then, this works. No other changes to the Javascript are required.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem with Rails 5 and the latest version of turbolinks(as of 8/24/17)

I had something similar. My issue was when navigating to another page withing my application and using autocomplete. it didnt work. after some research, I found that adding

```
$(document).addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
 // your code here
}
```

to my

> app/assets/javascripts/application.js

You can read some more about turbolinks here: [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I use `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {`
Also the gem "jquery-turbolinks" doesn't seem to be compatible with turbolinks 5.