# Rails 5/jQuery: On click touchstart event not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks-5

I'm trying to use a bourbon/refills componenet (sliding_panel) and I have `on('click touchstart')` event. I'm using this for my navigation menu. The event will work just fine on first page load but after that will stop. The event uses `toggleClass` to show and hide the menu. I'm wasn't sure if this was a turbolinks problem so I did some digging and found the jquery-turbolinks gem. I went through the installation instructions but same outcome. Has anyone else had this problem?

Code below:

**_navbar.html.erb**

```
<button type="button" class="js-menu-trigger sliding-panel-button">
 Click for Sliding Panel
</button>

<nav class="js-menu sliding-panel-content">
 <ul>
  <li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div class="js-menu-screen sliding-panel-fade-screen"></div>
```

**sliding_panel.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sliding-panel-button,.sliding-panel-fade-screen,.sliding-panel-close').on('click touchstart',function (e) {
 $('.sliding-panel-content,.sliding-panel-fade-screen').toggleClass('is-visible');
 e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

**sliding_panel.scss**

```
.sliding-panel-content {
  $action-color: #477DCA !default;
  $dark-gray: #333 !default;
  $sliding-panel-border-color: $dark-gray;
  $sliding-panel-background: lighten($sliding-panel-border-color, 5%);
  $sliding-panel-color: #fff;
  $sliding-panel-border: 1px solid $sliding-panel-border-color;
  $sliding-panel-background-hover: $action-color;
  $sliding-panel-color-hover: #fff;
  $sliding-panel-background-focus: lighten($sliding-panel-background, 5%);

  @include position(fixed, 0 auto 0 0);
  @include size(220px, 100%);
  background: $sliding-panel-background;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateX(-220px);
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  z-index: 999999;

  ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
  }

  li a {
    border-bottom: $sliding-panel-border;
    color: $sliding-panel-color;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;

    &:focus {
      background-color: $sliding-panel-background-focus;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: $sliding-panel-background-hover;
      color: $sliding-panel-color-hover;
    }
  }

  &.is-visible {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.sliding-panel-fade-screen {
  @include position(fixed, 0);
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 999998;

  &.is-visible {
    opacity: 0.4;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.sliding-panel-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  position: relative;

  img {
    height: 1.3em;
  }
}
```

These are exact copied exactly from the [bourbon/refills site here](https://refills.bourbon.io/components/).

Comment: I've added `data-turbolinks="false"` to the `nav` tag and it's working more that just once but not on all pages. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't listen to ready event, but to `page:load` event. So, the code will be something like this:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
 $('.sliding-panel-button,.sliding-panel-fade-screen,.sliding-panel-close').on('click touchstart',function (e) {
 $('.sliding-panel-content,.sliding-panel-fade-screen').toggleClass('is-visible');
 e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Source: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Hope it helps.

Comment: that makes the sliding panel not work at all. But I think that might be putting me on the right track.

Comment: @BB123 actually, I had experienced a lot of issues with jquery plugins that uses  $.ready on Rails applications with turbolinks. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had Turbolinks ~> 5.2. I went back to Turbolinks ~> 5.0.1 and then loaded the jQuery like so: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()` instead of using `ready()`. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958686/jquery-autocomplete-not-working-with-turbolinks) helped me figure out the solution.